# Want a code that detects custom status and gives the person a role on discord

Tags: discord, discord.js, roles, status

I am trying to make a code that searches a custom status for the phrase ".gg/RoundTable" and will then give the person a certain role I have in my server.
Here is my code so far , the code runs with no errors but it will not assign the role.

```js
    const Discord = require("discord.js")
    const client = new Discord.Client()
    
    const mySecret = process.env['TOKEN']
    
    client.login(mySecret)
    
    const roleID = 865801753462702090
    
    client.on('presenceUpdate', async (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
      const role = newPresence.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Pic Perms (.gg/RoundTable)');
      const status = ".gg/RoundTable"
      const member = newPresence.member
    
       console.log(member.user.presence.activities[0].state)
      if(member.presence.activities[0].state.includes(status)){
        return newPresence.member.roles.add(roleID)
      } else {
        if(member.roles.cache.has(roleID)) {
          newPresence.member.roles.remove(roleID)
        }
      }
    })
```

Comment: Consider putting quotes `"` around your `roleID`. This is to help prevent an integer overflow in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

const roleID = "851563088314105867";

client.on("presenceUpdate", async (_, newPresence) => {
  const role = newPresence.guild.roles.cache.get(roleID);
  const status = ".gg/RoundTable";
  const member = newPresence.member;

  if (member.presence.activities[0].state?.includes(status)) {
    return newPresence.member.roles.add(role);
  } else {
    if (member.roles.cache.has(role)) {
      newPresence.member.roles.remove(role);
    }
  }
});
    
client.login("your-token");
```

I'd recommend finding your [`role`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role) in the [`RoleManager.cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=get) using [`get()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=get) as you already have the `roleID` and then actually assign that role instead of the `roleID`. Note I added an [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) since if a user does not have a custom status `.state` will be `null`.